# Kinematics and electrostatics

Tags: electrostatics, kinematics, velocity

Suppose we have two opposite charges of charge $+4 \cdot 10^{-5}\,$C and $-4 \cdot 10^{-5}\,$C and mass 5$\,$g each, at a distance of 1$\,$m.

Now if they were released from rest then, all the potential energy ($\frac{k q_1 q_2}{r^2}$) of system would change to kinetic energy ($\frac{1}{2}mv^2$).

Equating these two equation and putting the values I got $v\approx75\,$ m/s. Now at what time is this the velocity of the particle I have gotten?

I don't think it's at t=0 sec as particle would take time to accelerate and gain velocity??

Comment: The potential energy of the system is not given by $\frac{kq_1q_2}{r^2}$, but by $\frac{kq_1q_2}{r}$

Answer (score 2):

> Now if they were released from rest then, all the potential energy
> ($\frac{kq_1q_2}{r^2}$) of system would change to kinetic energy
> ($\frac 12 mv^2$).
>
> Equating these two equation and ...

There is a minor flaw and a major misunderstanding in this reasoning.

The formula for the potential energy is $\frac{k q_1 q_2}{r}$,
not $\frac{k q_1 q_2}{r^2}$. And notice, because $q_1$ and $q_2$
have opposite signs the potential energy is actually negative here.
Calculating it at the beginning ($t=0)$ you get $-14.4\text{ J}$.

You are not allowed to just equate potential and kinetic energies
$E_\text{pot}$ and $E_\text{kin}$.
Instead, energy conservation says, their *sum* is constant over time:
$$E_\text{pot}+E_\text{kin}=\text{const}$$
or
$$\frac{k q_1 q_2}{r}+\frac{1}{2}m_1v_1^2+\frac{1}{2}m_2v_2^2=-14.4\text{ J}$$

When you release the two bodies their kinetic energy will
increase from zero to positive values.
And since the total energy remains constant,
the potential energy (starting from a negative value) will get even more negative.